# elasticsearch prevent search request on primary shards

Tags: elasticsearch

As I know elastic search will roud-robin search request to all node (primary and replica ).

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/replica-shards.html

Its mean that primary shard will get both read and write request. So Is there any way to force primary shards just received write data request other search request will be not routed here.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`preference`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-preference.html) to route the search requests only to replicas (`_replica`).